# What does the number after type means in var_dump(object) PHP?

Tags: php

For example, in the [manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php)

```
<?php
    class C {}

    function getC(): C {
        return new C;
    }

    var_dump(getC());
?>
```

Output

```
object(C)#1 (0) {
}
```

What does `#1`, `(0)` mean?

Answer (score 3):

The `#X` is the order of instantiation of the object and the `(X)` is the number of properties:

```
class C {
    public $a;
}
$a = new C;
$b = new C;

var_dump($b);  // instantiated second
var_dump($a);  // instantiated first
```

Yields `#1` for the first instantiated object and `#2` for the second and `(1)` for both since they have one property `a`:

```
object(C)#2 (1) {
  ["a"]=>
  NULL
}
object(C)#1 (1) {
  ["a"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`#1` is a unique identifier for each object, to allow you to tell when the same object appears in multiple places in the output.

`(0)` is the number of properties of the object. Since `C` has no properties, it's zero in this case.

Comment: What does it mean with a string? `array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(247) "..."
  [1]=>
  string(217) "..."
}` Is 247 and 217 the number of instances of strings before these were created? If so, why such a difference when the array was just created?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts It's the number of characters in the string.