# I var_dump an object type data, but what is #number mean? and why always increase when i reload my page

Tags: php, mysql, object

I try to var_dump my data, i got this result. what is this #949 #950 and why that #number always increase when i reload my page?

```
array(4) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#949 (4) { ["tanggal"]=> string(10) "2021-02-20" ["waktu"]=> string(5) "12:00" ["zoom"]=> string(5) "zoom1" ["token"]=> string(32) "4e03d86ced0713b685e66912d6287532" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#950 (4) { ["tanggal"]=> string(10) "2021-02-22" ["waktu"]=> string(5) "12:00" ["zoom"]=> string(5) "zoom3" ["token"]=> string(32) "ed5db365327bed0960e6cf7de45000ba" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#951 (4) { ["tanggal"]=> string(10) "2021-02-23" ["waktu"]=> string(5) "12:03" ["zoom"]=> string(5) "zoom4" ["token"]=> string(32) "c8a1d12016d39fd544e0497401571e5e" } [3]=> object(stdClass)#952 (4) { ["tanggal"]=> string(10) "2021-02-27" ["waktu"]=> string(5) "12:03" ["zoom"]=> string(5) "zoom5" ["token"]=> string(32) "a961c4066419aaac3afe728a704429e2" } }
```

Comment: Where is this coming from?  What code?  Those are not sharps...

Comment: Take a look at this article: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32384565/what-does-the-number-after-type-means-in-var-dumpobject-php)

Comment: @DarrenWoodson  I still didnt understand how it work and for what..

Comment: it from php, $absenke=json_decode($hasil2['absen']); var_dump($absenke);exit; @SethB

Comment: So the # is the order in which the object was instantiated, and it keeps going up as your page is holding onto some memory of previous renderings. Therefore each time you re-load the page and the array object in question is re-initialized it becomes say the 949th object to be instantiated. The number in parenthesis is the number of properties that object has.  So (4) means that object has 4 properties. Its just a way for var_dump to give you additional information about the object.

Comment: @DarrenWoodson how i can reset that #number? i just create that data object but why it count 949th?

Comment: I can't see the rest of your code so I could only guess why the number is climbing on each refresh, I'm not sure if you have some kind of unintentional loop or have 948 other objects you initialize first. We would need more of an example.

Comment: @Soekasir I would need to see more code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is #<some-number> next to object(someClass) in var\_dump of an object? I have an inference. Am I right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787893/what-is-some-number-next-to-objectsomeclass-in-var-dump-of-an-object-i-hav)

Comment: @sabaykebremso yess. ty